# Mongodb filter an array base on another array with aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

Below is the document example:

```
{
  "overview": {
    "date": "20230606",
    "key": "hot"
  },
  "features": {
    "color": ["y","y","r","b"],
    "size": [12,23,17,13]
  },
  "cost": {
    "min": [2,3,4,4],
    "max": [3,6,7,6]
  }
}
```

I want to get the filtered result of arrays "color" and "size" depends on "min" array.

Example expected result below when "min" is 4:

```
{
  "date": "20230606",
  "color": ["r","b"],
  "size": [17,13]
}
```

Could you show how to do with aggregate?

Comment: What do you mean by "when min is 4"? Are you providing the value of min through some input?

Comment: If refactoring the schema is possible, you may consider putting the attributes together in a single object like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZeNQG3ScYz6). MongoDB data are meant to be put together if they are expected to access together.

Comment: question is not clear ..  what is "depends on "min" array." ? is it you are trying to filter by min cost or something?